# Passing Arguments in Windows Application

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, arguments

I am making a application(desktop app), and need to fetch ids from DB and pass these ids to another desktop application.

How to achieve this?

Comment: not a real question: lacks detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is your answer. You can use command line argument passing in windows application. As to how to do this is written below.
You can Create a process and call the application to start and pass those arguments:

```
Process pro=new Process();
pro.StartInfo.FileName = @"ApplicationName.exe";
pro.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1 + " " + arg2;
pro.Start();

pro.WaitForExit();
```

in the second application get these values by following the below code:

```
var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (arguments.Length > 1)
{
productIdFirst = Convert.ToInt32(arguments[1]);
productIdSecond = Convert.ToInt32(arguments[2]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked...:)..This is what i am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you're talking about a website and you could pass it a query string. If that is the case then you should check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx :)

Comment: no, i am not making any website, i was making a console app

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Martim, that it is no clear if your tags "Windows" not perhaps mean "Website". But if you really mean "Windows" like you've tagged, you can use COM as Middleware. A german article already has great explanation with code samples. Languages can be translated.

http://www.activevb.de/tutorials/tut_middleware/middleware.html

Download Source Code

http://www.activevb.de/tutorials/tut_middleware/downloads/Middleware.zip